# What is the "iOS rich content paste pasteboard type" when copying from Safari?

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

When I copy text from a website in Safari, two pasteboard items are created. This is the output of [pasteboard items]

```
(
        {
        "Apple Web Archive pasteboard type" = < [...archive...] >;
        "public.text" = "pages of a journal,";
    },
        {
        "iOS rich content paste pasteboard type" = <694f5320 72696368 20636f6e 74656e74 20706173 74652070 61737465 626f6172 64207479 7065>;
    }
)
```

What is the "iOS rich content paste pasteboard type" all about? What does the data actually represent? Is this representation ever used by other apps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's been long time since this question was asked, but anyways looks like I've found the answer in [a patch for a WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=234687&action=prettypatch).

Here's a code snippet from the patch demonstrating that this pasteboard format is just a flag for UIKit. Not sure what a "two-step paste" is all about, though.

```
// Flag for UIKit to know that this copy contains rich content. This will trigger a two-step paste.
static NSString* webIOSPastePboardType = @"iOS rich content paste pasteboard type";
[representations setValue:webIOSPastePboardType forKey:webIOSPastePboardType];
```

Comment: Great research, thank you!